# jetbrains studio icon appears when I run android-studio

Tags: gnome3

I am using `gnome3.28` in `fedora 28`. For launching `android studio`, I am using the `.desktop` file as:

```
cat .local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Android Studio
GenericName=Google Android Studio - The intelligent Android IDE
Exec=env _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=androidstudio
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.21
```

Problem is, as shown in the screenshot, the `jetbrain-studio` appears when I launch android-studio.

Is there any way to get free from this jetbrain icon?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a bug. The workaround is to rename your `android-studio.desktop` file as `jetbrains-studio.desktop`.
That is, from a command prompt, type:
`mv ~/.local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop`

(Tested with GNOME Shell 3.28.2 on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: @BaRud if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks. It also works for Debian 9 (stretch) running GNOME 3.22.2.

Answer (score 0):

Open '.local/share/applications/' folder with root. Delete jetbrain-studio.desktop. And create your new desktop entry file.